# Merge and Combine Hash Values in an Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, merge

I'm building an array where I need to combine or merge all of the file paths in a hash with two values inside.

The input hash looks like this:

```
h = { "Apple_HLS(Media)"=>[
        "\\\\workspace1\\test-media.m3u8",
        "\\\\workspace1\\OTT-1\\segment_1.ts"
      ],
      "Apple_HLS_Prev(Media)"=>[
        "\\\\workspace1\\test-media-p.m3u8",
        "\\\\workspace1\\OTT-3\\test-media-p.m3u8"
      ]
    }
```

I tried this code:

```
outputs['output_files'] =
  inputs['output_files_hash'].
  select{ |k,v| k == 'Apple_HLS(Media)' }.
  values
```

And it works with only one value in the hash, which yields the file paths inside "*Apple_HLS*" value.

```
[["\\\\workspace1\\test-media.m3u8",
  "\\\\workspace1\\OTT-1\\segment_1.ts"]]
```

But I need to combine and merge the values of "*Apple_HLS_Prev*" and include it in the array output. I tried this code and it didn't merge the values, instead it shows blank.

**EDIT: I was expecting a merged and combined output of the array like this:**

```
[["\\\\workspace1\\test-media.m3u8",
  "\\\\workspace1\\OTT-1\\segment_1.ts",
  "\\\\workspace1\\test-media-p.m3u8",
  "\\\\workspace1\\OTT-3\\test-media-p.m3u8"]]
```

Hope you can answer. Thanks guys!

Comment: Where is the expected output?

Comment: I would suggest you update your question to show the desired output array as well.

Comment: Hi, sorry! Already included the desired output now in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented,  you need to show what you actually expect your output to be but I think I understand what you are looking for.

Here is a hash that I think matches the format of your hash.

```
my_hash = {key1: [:key1_value1, :key1_value2],key2: [:key2_value1, :key2_value2], key3: [:key3_value1, :key3_value2]}
```

To merge all the values just get the values,  which will be a array of 2 element arrays,  and then flatten that in to an single array.

```
my_hash.values.flatten
```

returns:

```
[:key1_value1, :key1_value2, :key2_value1, :key2_value2, :key3_value1, :key3_value2]
```

If you want to retain the value pairs, then just don't flatten the values.

```
my_hash.values
```

returns:

```
[[:key1_value1, :key1_value2], [:key2_value1, :key2_value2], [:key3_value1, :key3_value2]]
```

If you only want to select a subset of the entries in your has you can do something like this:

```
my_hash.select {|k,v| [:key1, :key2].include? k}.values.flatten
```

which returns:

```
[:key1_value1, :key1_value2, :key2_value1, :key2_value2]
```

The reason the following did not work is because as you saw the first select only returns the entry matching 'Apple_HLS(Media)' the second select is applied to the result of the first select which no longer includes the entry for 'Apple_HLS_Prev(Media)'

```
outputs['output_files'] = inputs['output_files_hash'].select{ |k,v| k == 'Apple_HLS(Media)' }.select{ |k,v| k == 'Apple_HLS_Prev(Media)' }.values
```

While I think what I posted (using the array `include?` method) above is cleaner, you might get what you want by saying the key should be Apple_HLS(Media) OR Apple_HLS_Prev(Media)

```
outputs['output_files'] = inputs['output_files_hash'].select{ |k,v| k == 'Apple_HLS(Media)' || k == 'Apple_HLS_Prev(Media)'}.values
```

but I think this is cleaner:

```
outputs['output_files'] = inputs['output_files_hash'].select { |k,v| ['Apple_HLS(Media)', 'Apple_HLS_Prev(Media)'].include? k }.values
```

Comment: So, technically, 'select' method only use one (1) entry from the hash?

Comment: No select will "select" all the entries that match your search criteria, so   `select{ |k,v| k == 'Apple_HLS(Media)' }` only matched the one entry,  if you try and take that result but try and select a entry with a different criteria such as `select{ |k,v| k == 'Apple_HLS(Media)' }` it will not find anything because that entry was removed by the first select.  That's why I used the OR or the Array#include? method.

Comment: Oh, so when I use the OR function, the values of both keys are combined?

Comment: select "filters" the hash into a new hash containing only the entries you specifiy  [see this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = { "Apple_HLS(Media)"=>[
        "\\\\workspace1\\test-media.m3u8",
        "\\\\workspace1\\OTT-1\\segment_1.ts"
      ],
      "Apple_HLS_Prev(Media)"=>[
        "\\\\workspace1\\test-media-p.m3u8",
        "\\\\workspace1\\OTT-3\\test-media-p.m3u8"
      ]
    }
    
[h.map {|k, v| v }.flatten]
#=> [["\\\\workspace1\\test-media.m3u8", "\\\\workspace1\\OTT-1\\segment_1.ts", "\\\\workspace1\\test-media-p.m3u8", "\\\\workspace1\\OTT-3\\test-media-p.m3u8"]]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).